# Asterisk cross platform compilation

Tags: c++, cygwin, asterisk

I am trying to compile asterisk from windows using netbeans c/c++ IDE. As i want to add some functionality into the existing code.

when i am running the configure file i got the following errors

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: .\configure
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: ./configure
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

I am very new to cross platform development. Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part seems just to say, that you should call configure not as `.\configure` but as `./configure`. The last line is the real error. As it says it can't run /bin/sh ./config.sub you should check that both files are correct and existent.

Do `ls -l ./config.sub` to see if the file exists and is readable by your user and `file ./config.sub` to ensure it is a shell script.

If config.sub seems correct, do

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

to make sure, that the interpreter exists and is executable.